# How to update Task Progress from loop?

Tags: java, progress-bar, task

I have a `Task` that runs several methods to accomplish the end result. I am updating a `ProgressBar` as I go, but need help with figuring out how to determine the equation needed to accurately reflect that progress.

My task runs through several "steps" until completion. However, one of those steps iterates through an `ArrayList` and I want my `ProgressBar` to update after each iteration, but I won't know the size of the `List` until run time.

For example, I want this loop to account for 75% of the overall progress, but instead of waiting for it to complete and then calling `updateProgress(75, 100)`, for example, I would like to update the `ProgressBar` after each iteration of the loop.

I just don't know what equation to use to make this work.

My pseudo method for the `Task`:

```
public Task<Void> convertTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                int totalSteps = 100;

                // Step one (fast)
                doThis();
                updateProgress(1, 100);

                // Step two (fast)
                doThisToo();
                updateProgress(2, 100);

                // Step three (iterates through an ArrayList)
                for (Clazz clazz :
                        listOfThings) {
                    // Do something with the list
                    updateProgress(?, ?); // <-- Need help figuring this out!
                }

                // Step four (fast)
                doThisLast();
                updateProgress(4, 100);

                return null;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: You mean something like `75.0 * current_index / listOfThings.size()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming for a total of 100% and your loop taking 75%

- doThis() -> 8%
- doThisToo() -> 8%
- loop -> 75%
- doThisLast() -> remaining 9%

Just calculate the % that one item in the list represents, and update by this amount after processing each item:
This solution calculates the `stepPerThing` as a double and adds to the stepValue we have before the loop to avoid truncating/rounding errors.

```
protected void call()  throws Exception {

  int totalSteps = 100;
  int currentStep = 0;

  // Step one (fast)
  doThis();
  currentStep += 8;
  updateProgress(currentStep, totalSteps);

  // Step two (fast)
  doThisToo();
  currentStep += 8;
  updateProgress(currentStep, totalSteps);

  // Step three (iterates through an ArrayList)
  int nbThings = listOfThings.length;
  double stepPerThing = 75d / (double)nbThings;
  int stepBeforeLoop = currentStep;
  for(int i = 0; i<nbThings; i++) {
    Class clazz = listOfThings[i];
    // Do something with the list
    int step = stepBeforeLoop + (int)((i+1)*stepPerThing);
    updateProgress(step, totalSteps);
  }

  // Step four (fast)
  doThisLast();
  updateProgress(totalSteps, totalSteps);
}
```

Assuming a 10 things array, it would do:

```
8/100
16/100
-- Loop starts here
23/100
31/100
38/100
46/100
53/100
61/100
68/100
76/100
83/100
91/100
-- Loop ends here
100/100
```